# Center absolute div nested in bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to center a dropdown div in the center of the screen on mobile (bootstrap xs). I tried to make a fiddle but the bootstrap isn't showing up correctly. The code can be found [here](http://www.loreleywines.be/index2.php#FAVORIETEN).

I can't align the div outside of it's container, causing a strange distribution on the screen. It works when I set the positionX of each dropdown-menu using a percentage, but different screen-resolutions give different results:

```
#winePrice .dropdown-content {
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(24%);
}
#wineType .dropdown-content {
    left: 0%;
    transform: translateX(-37%);
}
#wineLocation .dropdown-content {
    left: 0%;
    transform: translateX(-98%);
}
```

Without this adjustment it looks like this:

[image: wrong alignment]

Is there a cleaner way to force the absolute div to align to the window instead of its parent?

Answer (score 2):

Use position:fixed instead of  absolute. This will ensure that it is in the same position in the screen.

The following will set the top left point of the content to the center - then by translating it by -50% in both directions will bring the center of the element to that center point.

```
#winePrice .dropdown-content {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: It's not working, the alignment for the middle one is OK, the left and right ones are aligned to their parent one and go of screen.

Comment: Also, the height should remain as it is, so I removed the `top` from your code.